# Reuse command for object in a command for a collection of objects

Tags: c#, .net, cqrs

I have a CommandHandler that implements some logic for an object and commits context (in my case RavenDb IDocumentSession). I need to implement the same logic for a collection of objects. The first idea is to create a new CommandHandler which would call the first CommandHandler for each object in the foreach. But it would result in N database roundtrips.

The best idea I came to was to create a base CommandHandler with the logic itself but without context commit. Something like this:

```
internal class AuditProductCommandHandler : AuditProductCommandHandlerBase, ICommandHandler<AuditProductCommand>
{
    private readonly IDocumentSession _documentSession;

    public AuditProductCommandHandler(IDocumentSession documentSession)
    {
        _documentSession = documentSession;
    }

    public void Execute(AuditProductCommand command)
    {
        AuditProduct(command.Product);

        _documentSession.SaveChanges();
    }
}

internal class AuditProductsCommandHandler : AuditProductCommandHandlerBase, ICommandHandler<AuditProductsCommand>
{
    private readonly IDocumentSession _documentSession;

    public AuditProductsCommandHandler(IDocumentSession documentSession)
    {
        _documentSession = documentSession;
    }

    public void Execute(AuditProductsCommand command)
    {
        foreach (var product in command.Products)
        {
            AuditProduct(product);
        }

        _documentSession.SaveChanges();
    }
}

internal class AuditProductCommandHandlerBase
{
    protected void AuditProduct(Product product)
    {
      //logic itself 
    }
}
```

For some reason I feel uncomfortable about this solution. Are there any better options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose to remove `_documentSession.SaveChanges()` altogether from the command handler implementation and move the responsibility to the caller. The caller can then decide if they have to chain multiple command handlers or multiple DB operations and then call the `SaveChanges()` after that. Since caller is responsible for creating/sending the `IDocumentSession` object, they can take the responsibility of saving and disposing of it too.